# Filter causing infinite digest cycle AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have 'ng-repeat' loop inside my template. I have added my custom filter:

```
.filter('toJson', function() {
  return function(items, uppercase) {
     return items = angular.fromJson(items);
  };
});
```

Problem is it will cause infinite loop. Any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Change filter name, because `angularjs` already have `toJson` filter

So, you can use it, also there is another json filter `{{data | json}}`